# Cant connect nodes in shader editor

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I am in shader editor(blender ver. 2.92) and I simply can not connect nodes between each other. These lines, which should connect those little dots in nodes do not appear and I do not know what to do. I've searched how to deal with this problem for a week and still...Maybe somebody here knows how can I fix that?

I just need to connect these yellow Color dots and I ve tried all sorts of combinations, which I ve found on the forum such as: <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> and <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.
File below

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried doing a factory reset? File > defaults > Load factory settings

Comment: What exactly are you doing to try connecting the nodes together? Please [edit] your question and add a little more visual information. [Gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) are useful to add short visual information in these cases. `Ctrl+T` on the output node will add a new world setup if you have node wrangler installed anyway...

Comment: @Mobin thanks for the advice, but didnt work out for me...guess because I am a newbie and settings are not guilty :D

Comment: @Chris Added, hope it helps!

Comment: Tested your file and it's working fine. I guess it's your graphics card, make sure latest drivers are installed otherwise consider to file a bug report (Help > Report a Bug).

Comment: @brockmann oh? thanks for help, hope i ll deal with it :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same problem working in 3.0.

I had two windows with shading workspace open, specifically *Nodes* window.
If I closed one, connectivity and movability returned.

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the distance between the nodes you want to connect a bit and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Note that <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> and <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> mentioned in the question are functions from the [Node Wrangler Addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_wrangler.html) (shipped with Blender but disabled by default).

While they do create connections, it isn't their primary purposes:

- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> : *Connect an output of the selected node to the final output of the node tree (...) to preview its output in the viewport.*
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> : *Add a setup of a texture node, Texture Coordinate, and Mapping nodes to any shader node.*

---

The basic way of connecting nodes that should always work is to click and drag a socket, and drop it to another node's socket:

[image]

If no noodle appears while doing this, it sounds like either a graphics issue due to your system, or a bug.

You can check if your system meets Blender's requirements on : [Requirements — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)

To update your drivers, the rule of thumbs is to simply get the latest available. But if you are interested in Cycles GPU rendering, you might also need to get a specific "variant" of your manufacturer's drivers. Hence, you should probably look at [GPU Rendering — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware)

If you confirmed your hardware is within Blender's target and your graphics driver is up-to-date, yet still have issues, please report a bug using Blender's menu Help ► Report A Bug.